# I am using AllenBrowne Concatrelated function and it's not working

Tags: function, ms-access, concatenation

Hi I need help with my query.

My data looks like this:

Table: moms

```
mom_name  
Alice  
Christina  
Mandy
```

Table kids:

```
mom_name    kid_name
Christina   Charles
Christina   Jack
Alice       Mandy
Alice       Joe
Alice       Jeff
Mandy       Alan
Mandy       Omar
```

and I am typing this query

```
SELECT distinct Moms.mom_name, 
concatrelated("[kid_name]","[kids]","mom_name = " & [moms.mom_name] & """" ) AS Expr1
FROM Moms ;
```

And I get this error:

```
Error 3075: Syntax error in string in query expression 'mom_name = Alice"'.
```

and the error repeats over every mom name in the table.. where is my mistake??

Comment: You have the closing double quotes, but no opening ones. It's easier with single quotes, see Gustav's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```
Select Distinct 
    Moms.mom_name, 
    ConcatRelated("[kid_name]","[kids]","mom_name = '" & [moms.mom_name] & "'") AS Kids
From 
    Moms;
```