# Changing how a Dataset is presented

Tags: sql, excel

I looked through the previous questions but could not find something I could apply here'
I have several bins that have automatic dispensing equipment associated.  On the PLC trigger, I am recording the values of some attributes for a specific bin to a table.  This is Wonderware Alarms and Events database, so for each attribute to be saved, an entry is generated.  Each entry carries the same timestamp:

[![Data Currently returned]
EventStamp,TagName,Description,Value,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Bin_Slow_Setting,Carbon Log Bin Slow Setting,221,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Bin_Weigh_Time,Carbon Log Bin Weigh Time,53,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Daybin_Weight,Carbon Log Daybin Weight,6200,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Bin_Target,Carbon Log Bin Target,1126,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Bin_Bump_Setting,Carbon Log Bin Bump Setting,15,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Bin_Fast_Setting,Carbon Log Bin Fast Setting,850,,,,,
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02.C_Al_Bin_Actual,Carbon Log Bin Actual,1118,,,,,

I need to be transforming this so I can present it by timestamp of the event as:

EventStamp,Bin,Slow_Setting,Weigh_Time, Daybin Weight,Bin Target,Bump Setting,Fast Setting, Actual
03/05/21 08:24:30.950,C_Bin_M621_02,221,53,6200,1126,15,850,1118
03/05/21 08:11:00.983,C_Bin_M621_02,221,43,6320,1126,15,850,1125
03/05/21 08:09:28.890,C_Bin_M621_02,221,54,6430,1126,15,850,1132

I have heard of Pivot and Unpivot, but I think you need an aggregate function, which I don't need; all I am trying to do is use the timestamp as common value for all 7 additional ones.
Is there a programmatic way, via either SQL Server or Excel macro, to obtain this?

Thank you

Comment: If you present this data as text, rather than pictures (ideally with a `CREATE TABLE` script and `INSERT` statements, but even a [regular table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) would do (in Github Markdown)) it's much easier for people to write queries and test them.

Comment: Is there a way for me to attach a csv file maybe?  Even this small set of data is too large for the text box

Comment: Files cannot be attached, links to downloadable files can be but that is not in compliance with SO model - all data needed to evaluate issue should be within question. There are other forums where files can be attached to post. Looks like need to do an aggregate query. Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871627/i-am-using-allenbrowne-concatrelated-function-and-its-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Are you using System Platform or just Intouch HMI? What version?
Are you literally creating your own table upon the trigger?
Do you not have a Wonderware Historian in the system that you could use?  In that product, there is a wide history retrieval option available where you would just request a set of tags by timestamp - returning the data in your desired format.
In the historian product there is also specifically an Event Tag that can be configured that would "automatically" link the data when the trigger is true.